# Can a Citrix NetScaler loadbalance based on the path portion of a URL?

Tags: citrix, netscaler

So I have a domain hosting two lovely applications thus...

```
http://intranet.lan:80/firstapp
http://intranet.lan:80/secondapp
```

And two physical boxes serving them up

```
http://box1.lan:80/firstapp
http://box1.lan:80/secondapp

http://box2.lan:80/firstapp
http://box2.lan:80/secondapp
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to route these two applications based on their paths.

The apps both have a servlet/endpoint for checking availability

E.g.

```
http://box2.lan:80/firstapp/ok    -- returns 200 OK if app is running
http://box2.lan:80/secondapp/ok
```

I'd like the *NetScaler* to only send traffic for a given path to a physical server if the endpoint is okay.

Is this possible? What are the terms I should be looking for in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. NetScaler can do that.

**CSVS**
You will have to create a "Content Switching Virtual Server" (CSVS). This will be the traffic cop directing traffic either to the left or the right.

**LBVS**
Next stop for the traffic will be a "Load Balancing Virtual Server" (LBVS). This will accept traffic from the CSVS and direct it to the backend servers.

**Backend health**
Only good backend servers will receive the traffic. This is decided by one or more "monitors". (Starting with a simple ping monitor to more advanced PERL scripts that actually log in to the backend. Default is ping.) If none of the backend servers are up, then you can deliver a "Sorry!" HTML-page from the server. (But I don't know if this will be satisfactory in your case.)

**Links**

1. See this blog article for how to set up basic content switching: (still for firmware version 9, but the same ideas apply)
   http://pe-kay.blogspot.de/2011/08/configuring-content-switching-in.html
2. Citrix documentation about basic content switching: http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/netscaler-content-switching-93/ns-cs-basicconfig-policies-tsk.html